# How to use IN operator with a GET request of Yii2REST web service

Tags: php, yii2

The documentation of Yii2 REST Web Services explain that we can filter the searched collection through query params passed via URL in a GET HTTP request.

From doc:
"Addionally, you can sort collections like http://localhost/users?sort=email or http://localhost/users?sort=-email. **Filtering collections** like http://localhost/users?filter[id]=10 or http://localhost/users?filter[email][like]=gmail.com could be implemented using **data filters**"

My question is how to use query params for an IN condition?

The IN condition is supported by data filter class of the framework but It does not work as I am doing it. I tried these:

http://localhost/api/v1/users?filter[id][in][]=1,2,3 (return empty response)
http://localhost/api/v1/users?filter[id][in]=[1,2,3] (return error message 'Operator "in" requires multiple operands.')

...and other ways same situation

Comment: Could we just update the search model, and check if the value is an array, then use the "IN" operator (?)

Comment: Can you add the code inside public function actions() of your UserController? Propably there will be the "searchModel" definition.

Comment: User controller extends yii\rest\ActiveController and actions is the default implemented by it. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html

Comment: Which yii2 version are you using? In the latest, you need to setup the searchModel http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-indexaction.html#$dataFilter-detail

Comment: Look at searchModel @JannesBotis [
            'class' => 'yii\data\ActiveDataFilter',
            'searchModel' => function () {
                return (new DynamicModel(['id' => null, 'username' => null, 'email' => null]))
                    ->addRule('id', 'integer')->addRule(['username', 'email'], 'string');
            },
        ];

Comment: @alvarofvr where are you using that particular code section?

Comment: I have a class AActiveController that extend from ActiveController. In that class i ovverride function actions() and in this function i have that peace of code. But all work perfectly only problem is how to use that IN condition in GET, not one explained example in web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys it would seem that by specifying the parameter operator in GET there is no way to query with an IN condition so solution is this:

```
http://localhost/api/v1/users?filter[id][]=1&filter[id][]=2&filter[id][]=3
```

Becouse Yii will convert it into an IN query see the
[example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#hash-format)

N.B.: Without specifying the [in] operator in URI otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 3):

until you post the code where you instantiate and load your DataFilter i'm not sure if this helps you.

.. so, based on the usecase in your question i'm assuming you're using
`$dataFilter->load(Yii::$app->request->queryParams)`

therefore this should be the proper way to have your query params formatted if you want them to evaluate corectly

```
?filter[id][in][]=1&filter[id][in][]=2&filter[id][in][]=3
```

based on these examples in the docs [data filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-datafilter.html) and [using data filters](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-providers.md#filtering-data-providers-using-data-filters-)

Comment: Hi csminb, I tried to use your answer but still not works.  I don't think is the correct mode using filter query params for IN condition in that mode. You said using $ dataFilter-> load (Yii :: $ app-> request-> queryParams) I actually did not implement code. I use directly the framework to build the condition